# Access to default database trough dependency injection not working in Play 2.8

Tags: java, mysql, dependency-injection, playframework, guice

I have set up the database connection in my Play 2.8.8 project's `application.conf` like this:

```
db.default.driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/mytable?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true"
db.default.username="someuser"
db.default.password="somepass"
```

I can see Play bring that connection up and down in Terminal, so I assume that setup is correct.

If I then want to access the default database in a helper class, injection appears to not work, since the value of `database` is always `null` when calling `MyDatabase.getDatabase()`, printing `Database == null`.

```
package mytools;

import javax.inject.*;

import play.*;
import play.db.*;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Date;

public class MyDatabase
{
    @Inject Database database;
    public Connection dbConnection;

    public static MyDatabase getDatabase()
    {
        MyDatabase db;
        
        db = new MyDatabase();

        System.out.println((db.database != null) ? "Database != null" : "Database == null");

        db.dbConnection = db.database.getConnection();

        db.lastStatement = null;
        
        return (db);
    }

    // …
}
```

I have searched the web and SO extensively, but couldn't find any hint at why injection might not work here - or how to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour: injection only works for instances of `MyDatabase` created by the framework, not instances created manually by `new MyDatabase()` like you are doing.

You should inject a `MyDatabase` instance with `@Inject` in the code where you need it (controller or service for instance..).